# In Excel VBA, is possible to get the activecell.value in find/replace dialog box?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, is possible to get the activecell.value in find/replace dialog box, in 'find what' field? Thank you.
I just know to open dialog with sendkeys or Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaFind).Show
but how to pass acvtivecell ?

Comment: You have effectively answered your own question! Use `activecell.value`

Comment: enough to think positive or what ? :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this code:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaFind).Show (ActiveCell.value)
```

Comment: thank you! it's working. but dialog looks different, no options. i need to search whithin workbook.

Comment: I've tried to find "Find & Replace" dialog box, but no success. I've only found `xlDialogFormulaReplace` for replace, but I know it won't help you.

Another alternative is to use `Find` method, but it won't open any window or dialog box.

Comment: i checked, it search within all sheets. it's ok. except no report "n replaced"